# How do I do a filtering join using dates in R?

Tags: mysql, r, join, dplyr, filtering

I have one table with three columns: contracts, date, and the value of the contract at that date.

I want to join this to another table that has contracts and dates as well. The key would be contracts. However, the dates columns of each table very rarely line up one to one. How can I keep the date column on the latter table and use the contract fund value at the date nearest to that date?

The dirty solution is to do a cartesian product and then filter the important date by the other dates I have. However, that would be costly for me since there are 42 million rows in the first table and only about 4000 rows in the second table. So I was thinking about implementing a filtering join using the dates in the second table

```
first <- tibble(contract = c(123124,1321412,312312),
                date = c(2016-02-09, 2016-03-09, 2014-01-08),
                value = c(20210, 34324, 31231))
second <- tibble(contract = c(123124, 1321412, 312312),
                 date = c(2015-03-09, 2014-03-09, 2014-01-08))
# if I join by contract key I think I could then filter doing something like this to get contract value at a time a month ahead or behind to get a reasonable approximation.
joined 'pipe'
  filter((date.x + 30) < date.y, (date.x - 30) > date.y))
# but this would be inefficient. is there a better solution?
```

Comment: The `data.table` package allows "non-equi joins", if you search for that keyword you can find examples. `dplyr` does not currently support non-equi joins. Other than that, your best option is to do the joining in SQL. I see you have the `mysql` tag, are you also open to MySQL answer?

Comment: Whatever system you use, under the hood it will be doing the general procedure you propose: cartesian join then filter. All of those comparisons have to be made to arrive at the correct result. But SQL or `data.table` will probably be able to do it in a more memory-efficient and/or computationally-efficient way, especially if you key on the date columns so the algorithms can assume they are pre-sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will look up a non-equi join. I added SQL because I do have access to SQL but only as a last resort. I was under the impression dplyr was modeled on SQL syntax so I guess I was hoping for a direct translation.

Comment: `dplyr` is modeled on SQL in some ways, but this is a capability it doesn't have yet.

Comment: Got it. I'll delete my question.